# Getting TypeError: $A.run is not a function after Summer 16 Release

Tags: lightning

I am not using $A.run anywhere in the code. still I am getting below error:
TypeError: $A.run is not a function.

Facing this issue after Summer 16 Release.

Comment: Shipa you need to post question with the code snippets so you get most out of the community .This question is bound to get closed if you do not pay attention .Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had that happen in a few scenarios:

1. I need to refresh the page to get the latest component code to load in the Lightning Experience.  You can "restart" by going to https://<yourinstance>.lightning.force.com/one/one.app and navigating back to your page to be sure.
2. I still had the $A.run method in the code and didn't realize it. For that, the [Salesforce Lightning CLI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.202.0.lightning.meta/lightning/cli_intro.htm) tool can be run against local code. Or, in this case you could just search the local files (e.g., [find command](http://www.techradar.com/us/how-to/computing/apple/terminal-101-using-the-find-command-1305633), etc.) on your local machine.
3. I've made changes locally and thought I deployed them but didn't. For that, I go to the Developer Console and look at the actual code that is on the server and verify that the changes that I made locally got to the server.

I was able to successfully remove $A.run from my codebase in a Summer '16 pre-release org and in a Summer '16 org.